# Fetch return, error to convert nvarchar to bigint

Tags: reactjs, web-services, react-native, authentication, fetch

I'm new in react-native, I try to make a fetch request using GET for a login page. I talk to a WebService. The response is correct when I hardcode login and password but if I use my own variable like: this.state.login I have this following error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Erreur de conversion du type de données nvarchar en bigint.
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      à System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      à System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      à System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
>      à System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
>      à dataClub.DSMembreTableAdapters.TAMembreBureau.GetDataForLogin(String LICI_NUMERO, String LICI_MDP, Nullable`1 LOGINADMIN) dans C:\Users\vfelder\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClubOnline\dataClub\DSMembre.Designer.cs:ligne 3869
>      à ClubOnline.WebServices.AppliMobile.connexion(String p_login, String p_mdp) dans C:\Users\vfelder\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ClubOnline\ClubOnline\WebServices\AppliMobile.asmx.cs:ligne 46

This is my constructor and fetch request:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        login: '',
        password: ''
    }
}

userLogin(){
    fetch('myWebService?p_login=this.state.login&p_mdp=this.state.password',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
        })
        .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

And this is my TextInput and Button related to my state:

```
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({login: text})}
                    placeholder={'Identifiant'}
                    ref={"login"}
                    returnKeyType={'next'}
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={this.state.login}
                />
                <TextInput
                    editable={true}
                    onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({password: text})}
                    placeholder={"Mot de passe"}
                    ref={'password'}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    style={styles.input}
                    value={this.state.password}
                />
                <Button
                    onPress={this.userLogin.bind(this)}
                    style={styles.buttonContainer}
                    title={"Connexion"}>
                </Button>
```

I try to make a post request or directly use XMLHttpRequest but it allawys the same, if I use my own variable, this error is generate. I really don't know what I missed. I hope have been as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this.state.login` and `this.state.password` as string , not the value by putting them in single quotes `'`

```
fetch('your_url?p_login=this.state.login&p_mdp=this.state.password',
```

Change this line with one of below:

---

**Use proper single quotes**

```
fetch('your_url?p_login='+this.state.login+'&p_mdp='+this.state.password,
```

**OR : Use New ES6 syntax `${var}` :**

```
fetch(`your_url?p_login=${this.state.login}&p_mdp=${this.state.password}`,
```

> Note : I've replaced your url with your_url, so you can easily check the
>   changes you need to make